# compare a table with sys columns

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

It seems an easy question but I am comparing a table contain random tables and columns with syscolumns

this  query will give me the missing columns

```
select object_name(syscolumns.id) , syscolumns.name
from syscolumns
where not exists 
   (select 1 
    from CHECKINGTABLE 
    where object_name(CHECKINGTABLE.id) = object_name(syscolumns.id)
     and CHECKINGTABLE.name=syscolumns.name)
     and object_name(syscolumns.id) ='TAB1'
```

but in such way it will give me wrong results

```
   select object_name(syscolumns.id) , syscolumns.name
    from syscolumns , CHECKINGTABLE
    where not exists 
       (select 1 
        from CHECKINGTABLE 
        where object_name(CHECKINGTABLE.id) = object_name(syscolumns.id)
         and CHECKINGTABLE.name=syscolumns.name)
         and object_name(syscolumns.id) =object_name(CHECKINGTABLE.id)
```

what I am doing wrong ? I want a query to compare a table I own with syscolumns to identify the missing data in my table

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.  I do not have an ASE DB at hand but the syntax should be correct I hope.

```
SELECT syscolumns.id , syscolumns.name
FROM syscolumns LEFT OUTER JOIN CHECKINGTABLE
ON (CHECKINGTABLE.id = syscolumns.id 
AND CHECKINGTABLE.name=syscolumns.name)
WHERE CHECKINGTABLE.name IS NULL
```